# Qt datagram to structure result: mixed sequence

Tags: c++, qt, sequence, datagram

I'm reading datas from socket and putting received datas from datagram to HostMessage. but when i try to show HostMessage->MessageHeader, it shows invalid data. also datagram output looks like a little different according to wireshark output.

I fixed this problem by ntonl function (and applied on MessageHeader, not all of datagram!!), b is correct result. with this solution, I have to apply ntonl to all of struct members, and I have members over 100.

Do you have any solution or idea for fix this?

**Code:**

```
unsigned int ntonl(unsigned int a){
    unsigned int b;
    char* pA = (char*)&a;
    char* pB = (char*)&b;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(pA); i++){
        pB[i] = pA[(sizeof(pA)-1) - i];
    }

    return b;
}

void myDevice::processPendingDatagrams(){
    while (m_udpSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()){
    QByteArray datagram;
            datagram.resize(m_udpSocket->pendingDatagramSize());

            QHostAddress sender;
            quint16 senderPort;

            qint64 dataReceivedLength = m_udpSocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(),
                                                                  datagram.size(),
                                                                  &sender,
                                                                  &senderPort);

    tagHostMessage* HostMessage = (tagHostMessage*)datagram.data();

    qDebug("datagram: %x-%x-%x-%x", datagram.data()[0], datagram.data()[1], datagram.data()[2], datagram.data()[3]);
    qDebug()<<"msg header: " << HostMessage->MessageHeader[0] << "=" << HostMessage->MessageHeader;

    b = ntonl(HostMessage->MessageHeader[0])
}
```

my struct:

```
typedef struct tagHostMessage{
    unsigned int        MessageHeader[4];
    TMessageData MessageData;
    short int    CheckSum;

}THostMessage,*PHostMessage;
```

**Wireshark output (1024byte):**

```
0d:cc:97:e0:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:....
```

**qDebug outputs:**

```
datagram: d-ffffffcc-ffffff97-ffffffe0

msg header:  3768044557 = 0x9be9b8 

a = e097cc0d    
b = 0dcc97e0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're experiencing byte order problem. Since `QUdpSocket` inherits `QIODevice`, you can use `QDataStream` on it, and this class supports byte order conversion. Specify the byte order of incoming data:

```
QDataStream stream(m_udpSocket);
stream.setByteOrder(QDataStream::BigEndian); // or LittleEndian
```

And then you can receive data like that:

```
unsigned int b;
stream >> b;
```

Also `qToBigEndian`, `qToLittleEndian`,  `qFromBigEndian`, `qFromLittleEndian` functions may be useful.